# EllipticalE notation and how to find numerical value

Tags: calculus, integration

I am hoping someone can explain to me how to find the approximate numerical value of the following :

[image]

I do not understand the meaning of the vertical bar and am not grasping the wikipedia page.

Edit : I am not sure how to make this question clearer. I needed to understand the meaning of the vertical bar in the notation...

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=EllipticE%28pi%2C0.5%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation*}
E\left( \theta \mid k^{2}\right) =\int ^{\theta }_{0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-k^{2}\sin^{2} x}}
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
E\left( \pi \mid \frac{1}{2}\right) =\int ^{\pi }_{0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^{2} x}}
\end{equation*}
Hope this helps!

Comment: It does, and answers the question. However, I am having trouble integrating that function now. Any pointers for which method would be best here?

Comment: The functions have been given a special name, because they are NOT integrable by standard methods. They have precalculated values, and you should use these precalculated values. Kind of like the Beta and the Gamma functions.

Comment: Suggestion - The value of this integral is 3.70815.